# I have a gLua error: bad argument #1 to 'lower' (string expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I want to create a command that would change your model when typing "!swap" and make it so it would return to your previous model when you type it again and repeat.

I have tried ending the function and continuing on but that hasn't worked. I need someone to explain the error as I have never seen it before and google/gmod wiki doesn't show it either.

```
hook.Add( 'PlayerSay', 'PlayerSayExample', function (ply, text, team)
end )
    if ( string.sub( string.lower( text ), 1, 5 ) == "!swap" ) then
local model = ply:GetModel()
function GM:PlayerSetModel( ply ) end
else
end

    if model == ("models/Kleiner.mdl") then
        ply:SetModel("models/Eli.mdl")
    else
        ply:SetModel("models/Kleiner.mdl")
end
```

===================================

```
[ERROR] lua/swap2.lua:3: bad argument #1 to 'lower' (string expected, got nil)
  1. lower - [C]:-1
   2. unknown - lua/swap2.lua:3
```

===================================
above (between the breaks) is the error I am getting. It occurs on the "string.lower" bit on line 3 but I don't know what is actually wrong with the code, as I haven't seen the error before.

Comment: There is `end` right after `function (ply, text, team)`.  Do you really want this function to be empty?

Comment: The error means that `string.lower`'s argument #1 (`text`) must be a string, but is actually nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
hook.Add( 'PlayerSay', 'PlayerSayExample', function (ply, text, team)
end )
```

Means that your hook is empty.

If you do not define text before or after the hook, text is nil and will always throw this error. Here is your fix:

```
hook.Add( 'PlayerSay', 'PlayerSayExample', function (ply, text, team)
    if ( string.sub( string.lower( text ), 1, 5 ) == "!swap" ) then
       local model = ply:GetModel()
       function GM:PlayerSetModel( ply ) end
    else
    end

    if model == ("models/Kleiner.mdl") then
        ply:SetModel("models/Eli.mdl")
    else
        ply:SetModel("models/Kleiner.mdl")
    end 
end )
```